# Expandable Content

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I am having an issue with expandable content that I am trying to build. Here is the code https://codepen.io/derekb91/pen/ddpdyY, and it all works as it should, but I want the boxes to be visible again when you click back. So it will expand like it does now and hides the other boxes, but I want those boxes to come back after you click the expanded div back down. What am I missing?

```js
$(".clickable").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".expandable").find(".fillBox").toggle('slow', function() {
    $(this).closest(".expandable").toggleClass("expanded", function() {
      $(".expandable").not(".expanded").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.expandable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.expandable:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.expanded {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #333;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fillBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  background: orange;
}

.clickable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expandable">
  <button class="clickable">Click Me</button>
  <div class="fillBox"></div>
</div>

<div class="expandable">
  <button class="clickable">Click Me</button>
  <div class="fillBox"></div>
</div>

<div class="expandable">
  <button class="clickable">Click Me</button>
  <div class="fillBox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like it works as described

Comment: It works in the snippet (which I transposed from the code the OP provided) but doesn't work in your codepen.

Comment: It works by pushing the content down, but I want it to hide the other blue divs when opened with toggleClass expanded being the only one showing. Then when closed it will show the blue boxes again.